# How to unfocus TextField that has custom FocusNode?

Tags: flutter

I know that general answer to unfocusing is to use this piece of code: `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());`

But when TextField has custom focusNode, this code doesn't seem to work.

`SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');` still works, but it only removes the keyboard - field itself is still selected.

The code (irrelevant parts removed):

```
class RegisterScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final phoneNumberTEC = TextEditingController();
  final passwordTEC = TextEditingController();
  final passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return this.keyboardDismisser(
      context: context,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Register"),
        ),
        body: this.page(context),
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget keyboardDismisser({BuildContext context, Widget child}) {
    final gesture = GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        this.passwordFocusNode.unfocus();
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
      },
      child: child,
    );
    return gesture;
  }

  Widget page(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  this.phoneNumberTextField(context),
                  this.passwordTextField(context),
                ]
            ),
          ),
          // cutting irrelevant widgets out
          )
        ]
    );
  }

  Widget phoneNumberTextField(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: this.phoneNumberTEC,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Phone number"),
      onSubmitted: (string) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(this.passwordFocusNode);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget passwordTextField(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: this.passwordTEC,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
      obscureText: true,
      focusNode: this.passwordFocusNode,
      onSubmitted: (string) {
        this.performRegister(context);
      },
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: So testing this, I enter in a value into Phone number, press enter, enter a value into Password, press enter, the soft keyboard dismisses and the Password field is no longer focused. Is this not what you want? [Gif](https://i.imgur.com/JwlYtVS.gif)

Comment: @SnakeyHips I want both this behavior and losing focus by clicking outside of the keyboard. Right now, clicking outside of the keyboard works only for first textfield, which has no custom focusNode.

Comment: I don't seem to have any problems doing that? [Gif](https://i.imgur.com/ubQ5S2s.gif)

Comment: @SnakeyHips comment out ```SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');``` -- because it hides the keyboard but doesn't end editing textfield (cursor is still blinking there).

Comment: Still working fine for me? I did have to remove `this.performRegister(context);` because that method wasn't provided within your code. Maybe that method is causing the issue?

Answer (score 158):

Here is a similar answer to @kasiara's answer but another way.

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
_textEditingController.clear();
```

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666298/widgets-tree-rebuild-using-focusscope-ofcontext-unfocus This can cause widget tree rebuilds which in practice leads to some pretty odd side-effects. The suggested answer to that question works- use `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();` instead.

Comment: @BenRoberts Thanks! there was no FocusManager.instance at that time when this answer provided. I will check the doc for more info and update answer.

Answer (score 41):

In my case I had a `TextFormField` which I wanted to **remove focus** from and hide the keyboard if possible. The following code does both and clears TextField content.

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode()); //remove focus
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _textEditingController.clear()); // clear content
```

where *_textEditingController* is just a `TextEditingController(text: "")` held in widget's State.

Comment: Is it ok to create undisposed `FocusNode`s every time ??

Comment: @Ramesh-X i did some testing with this code : https://gist.github.com/llpinokio/b58d80501fcd7f9a3ac139bfe6e5a2a0 , and after watching the devtools memory tab, and triggering the garbage collector manually, the gc can collect those objects and delete them, but it does so in various times, one of them is when pushingReplacement screens in the app.
So, in conclusion i think it's best to create a dummy focusNode and dispose it in the current stateful widget.

Comment: No, it's not @Ramesh-X, create and dispose it later using a variable

Comment: WidgetsBinding.instance.focusManager.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
It's unfocus all focuses without creating new one☝️

Comment: I'm using this in the parent page to clear focus in it's children:
```dart
final focusNodeForUnfocussing = FocusNode();
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNodeForUnfocussing);
focusNodeForUnfocussing.unfocus();
focusNodeForUnfocussing.dispose();
```

Answer (score 21):

This works for the new Flutter version:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (_) {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.focusedChild?.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: TextField())),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

similar to @Blasanka , but more shorter.
Put this inside a GestureDetector that wraps the whole page.

```
onTap: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      new TextEditingController().clear();
    },
```

Answer (score 14):

you may have seen some people use this approach:

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```

in this approach you are creating a FocusNode on the fly and not disposing it. while this also works but it's not recommended because FocusNode's are persistence objects and you should dispose them to avoid memory leaks:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
    }
```

check out this [link](https://flutterigniter.com/dismiss-keyboard-form-lose-focus/). the author has great explanation of how to do it in the best and right way.have a nice day:)

Comment: Only `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());` worked for me.

Comment: Will this be cleaned up by garbage collection? Is the freshly created FocusNode being disposed after it has been unselected?

Answer (score 9):

Comes out, I didn't manage the lifecycle of FocusNode properly: https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/focus

Thus, following code did work for me:

```
class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterScreenState createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  final phoneNumberTEC = TextEditingController();
  final passwordTEC = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode passwordFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    this.passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    this.passwordFocusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return this.keyboardDismisser(
      context: context,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Register"),
        ),
        body: this.page(context),
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget keyboardDismisser({BuildContext context, Widget child}) {
    final gesture = GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        debugPrint("!!!");
      },
      child: child,
    );
    return gesture;
  }

// ...

}
```

Thanks for [@SnakeyHips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8216367/snakeyhips) for help - inability to reproduce the issue when it was clearly reproducible on my side gave me some thoughts :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `onTapOutside` in `TextFormField`.

```dart
TextFormField(
onTapOutside: (event) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
...
)
```

Comment: This looks as the best way to me and also works for usual `TextField`. Any disadvantages of this in comparison to the most prefered answer, as there were so many issues with the creation with a new unused FocusNode ?

Answer (score 8):

just wrap your scaffold with GestureDetector,then put
`FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();`
inside the onTap Function

Comment: Hi, this answer has already been given by another user. You can add a comment to that user's answer if you like.

Answer (score 7):

Wrap the page Root Widget with GestureDetector Widget. That's work for me

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      new TextEditingController().clear();
    },
      child: _yourPageRootWidget(..)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently using the top accepted answers (`FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` or `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());`) can *ocassionally* cause widget tree rebuilds and a can even make it so it's impossible to re-focus the widget you un-focus.

As an alternative, this appears to work as expected / not cause intermittent bugs.

`FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();`

Answer (score 1):

I modified [@Axel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65448041/10023840) answer because I detected that on a screen with scroll, like SingleChildScrollView, the behavior is not as desired, since when scrolling the screen the keyboard hides, and we don't always want this (in a form, for example), so , replacing the Listener with a GestureDetector this problem is solved. See below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
            currentFocus.focusedChild?.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: TextField())),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it if you want to unfocus from the text field onTap: () {
WidgetsBinding.instance.focusManager.primaryFocus?.unfocus();}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
currentFocus.unfocus();
}
return Material(
child: Scaffold(
```

Only add new function(page) header , ( back main screen auto close keyboard )